# Having trouble with recurring characters in roster C#

Tags: c#

Have made a list of 15 character names as well as the the players that take these names in my list of players. I need to assign 2 teams of 5 from the roster and I'm struggling to understand how I can do it without recurring characters popping up.

```
string playerName;
List<string> nameLibrary = new List<string> {"Tim", "Smithy", "Bill", "Max", "Ryan", "Johnathon", "Brisbane", "Pearly Whites", "Old Mate", "Shanequia", "Davo", "Ben", "Big Shaq", "John Cena", "King Thing", "Doug"};

void Start ()
{
    playerName = name;
    List<Player> myListOfPlayers = new List<Player>();

    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
    {
        int randName = Random.Range(0, nameLibrary.Count);
        name = nameLibrary[randName];
        nameLibrary.Remove(name);

        Player somePlayer = new Player();
        somePlayer.Setup(name);
        myListOfPlayers.Add(somePlayer);
    }

    List<Player> team1 = new List<Player>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        Player Player1 = new Player();
        team1.Add(myListOfPlayers[Random.Range(0, 15)]);
        myListOfPlayers.Remove(Player1);
    }

    // Display team 1
    Debug.Log ("Team 1");
    foreach (Player Player1 in team1) 
    {
        Player1.PrintLine();
    }

    List<Player> team2 = new List<Player>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        Player Player2 = new Player();
        team2.Add (myListOfPlayers [Random.Range (0, 15)]);
        myListOfPlayers.Remove (Player2);
    }

    // Display team 2
    Debug.Log ("Team 2");
    foreach (Player Player2 in team2) 
    {
        Player2.PrintLine();
    }
```

Comment: When you pick a player, actually pick it from the list. Meaning remove it. Or shuffle the list and then just take the first n from there. Don’t use random to access a static list.

Comment: You are better off shuffling, picking from list and removing isn't truly random and will cause a bias.

Answer (score 1):

I would do what Sami suggessted and create a shuffle method. Removing from a list will cause a bias (see [Fisher Yates](https://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle) for explanation).

Create a Shufflie method (I didn't write this but have used it for other projects):

```
public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    Random rng = new Random();
    int n = list.Count;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
        T value = list[k];
        list[k] = list[n];
        list[n] = value;
     }

     return (List<T>)list;
}
```

Vastly simplify your code:

```
var names = new List<string>();
/* add your names  */
names.Shuffle();

var team1 = names.Take(5);
var team2 = names.Skip(5).Take(5);
```

Comment: I'd like to add that `Shuffle()` here is an *Extension method*, which means that for it to work it must be placed in a static class (e.g. `public static class ShuffleHelper { ... }`). Also `return list;` should work, the type cast is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @Peter B, also this uses the Fisher Yates algorithm. Here is more info if you are interested: https://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle